# WIN UI 3 and UWP life cycle

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, winui-3

I have created an application in `WIN-UI-3` and I am trying to get UWP life cycle `hooks/events` in `win-ui-3`. Nevertheless, I am unable to find any life cycle `hooks/events` in it.

This is what my `.csprod` file looks like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
<RootNamespace>App3</RootNamespace>
<ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
<Platforms>x86;x64;arm64</Platforms>
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
<UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
</PropertyGroup>



<!-- Workaround for https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/17890 -->
<PropertyGroup>
<NoWarn>CA1416, $(NoWarn)</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>



<ItemGroup>
<Manifest Include="$(ApplicationManifest)" />
</ItemGroup>



<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ProjectReunion" Version="0.8.0" />
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

What I am actually trying is to create an activity monitoring application, something like hubstuff, but I do not know if I am on right path.

Comment: Could you please clarify what hooks/events you are looking for, any examples? (Also it is time to upgrade to WindowsAppSdk 1.0 from Reunion 0.8)

Answer (score 2):

The UWP app model is not supported in the stable production ready release of WinUI 3 that you are targeting in your project file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ProjectReunion" Version="0.8.0" />
```

If you install the [1.0.0-experimental1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/experimental-channel#version-10-experimental-100-experimental1?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) version, there is an `[Experimental] Blank App (WinUI 3 in UWP)` project template that you can use to create a UWP app based on the WinUI3 library.

Note that the experimental version is **not supported** for use in production environments, and apps that use the experimental releases cannot be published to the Microsoft Store. Experimental features may also be removed from the next release, or may never be released at all.